# Is it possible to define RTK Query queries without QueryArgs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

The definition for a query in RTK Query is `query<ResultType, QueryArg>`. All of this is fine for queries where I actually need to send parameters to the API. However, I have some endpoints which don't require anything to be sent (something like getAllX). What can I pass as QueryArg here in the template? It won't accept having one argument.

So far I've used types like `undefined` and `null` to denote that nothing needs to be sent, but it looks ugly when you use the hook: `const {...} = useGetXQuery(undefined)`, and I'm pretty sure there has to be a better way, but scouring the internet yielded no results.

Comment: Have you tried passing empty object like `{}`? It's way cleaner

Comment: @JkAlombro yup, I was just hoping to have no parameters in there. I found the solution though, posted it as an answer. I totally forgot about the `void` type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured it out, you need to use `void` as a type, then you can use the hook like this: `const {...} = useGetXQuery()`.

Comment: FWIW this _is_ mentioned in our docs, at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-query-and-mutation-endpoints , although it's sorta buried: "If `query` doesn't have a parameter, then `void` type has to be provided explicitly."

Comment: Ah, thanks @markerikson, I completely missed it.

Comment: I missed this too. I think this should be more conspicuous some examples online use undefined but it's ugly this one is more correct. cc: @markerikson